# sass does not work in my react js project

Tags: reactjs, sass

I installed sass-loader and I followed all the steps from this [article](https://tuhub.ru/frontend/podklyuchaem-sass-k-instrumentu-create-react-app/), but still the scss file is not recognized for some reason. Nothing was changed.
Could u pls point out to my mistakes.

here u can see my web.config.dev.js file [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Feruza/zx2wm4jt/)
and I did `import "./styles/style.scss";` in App.js component

Comment: You attach wrong jsfiddle

Comment: @SlawaEremkin oh yeah sorry( now it is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsfiddle you use config for webpack1(article about webpack1 too), so you should use different syntax for including sass support, example of config below:

```
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
              ident: "postcss",
              plugins: () => [
                require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    ">1%",
                    "last 4 versions",
                    "Firefox ESR",
                    "not ie < 9" 
                  ],
                  flexbox: "no-2009"
                })
              ]
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
```